# ios alternate 4 colours

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to give 4 cells different colours and then repeat it. (so not zebra style table, but using 4)
Why is this not working?
I'm getting only 2 colours....

```
if (indexPath.row % 4 == 0)
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"35a8e1"]];
if (indexPath.row % 4 == 1)
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"5cb14c"]];
if (indexPath.row % 4 == 2)
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"ec292d"]];
else
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"ee8c1d"]];




+(UIColor*)colorFromHexString:(NSString*)hex
{
    NSString *cString = [[hex stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];

    // String should be 6 or 8 characters
    if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor grayColor];

    // strip 0X if it appears
    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];

    if ([cString length] != 6) return  [UIColor grayColor];

    // Separate into r, g, b substrings
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 2;
    NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 2;
    NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 4;
    NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    // Scan values
    unsigned int r, g, b;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)
                           green:((float) g / 255.0f)
                            blue:((float) b / 255.0f)
                           alpha:1.0f];
}
```

Comment: There isn't a `colorFromHexString:` class method in `UIColor`. Did you create a category of UIColor ? If you did, post your code please.

Comment: yes I did, which comes from SA as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
if (indexPath.row % 4 == 0)
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"35a8e1"]];
else if (indexPath.row % 4 == 1)
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"5cb14c"]];
else if (indexPath.row % 4 == 2)
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"ec292d"]];
else
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"ee8c1d"]];
```

Comment: Oops, looks like you beat me to it by a few seconds!

Comment: Long if/else chains are awful to read, why not switch(indexPath.row%4){   case 0: //etc. } //edit I didn't see this in the answer below, sorry, carry on :)

Answer (score 2):

I would implement the following, to make it easier to deduct what is actually happening:

```
NSUInteger index = indexPath.row;

if (index % 4 == 0) {
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"35a8e1"]];
} else if (index % 4 == 1) {
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"5cb14c"]];
} else if (index % 4 == 2) {
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"ec292d"]];
} else {
    [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"ee8c1d"]];
}
```

When written this way, your code is forced to do only a *single* operation.

Also, I would set a breakpoint on the first if statement, and step through the entire statement to see which one is getting executed.

---

Alternately, it might make things a bit clearer to use a switch statement:

```
 switch (indexPath.row % 4) {
 case 0:
      [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"35a8e1"]];
      break;
 case 1:
      [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"5cb14c"]];
      break;
 case 2:
      [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"ec292d"]];
      break;
 case 3:
      [cell setColor:[UIColor colorFromHexString:@"ee8c1d"]];
      break;
}
```